# The use of whom with comparative

Tags: sentence

I want to combine the following two sentences :

Don't compare yourself to your friends.
You were better than your friends in the past.

I thought about saying :
Don't compare yourself to your friends whom you were better than. 
But this sentence is very odd .Im not it even makes any sense. Can someone please tell me what is the correct form. Thank you

Comment: “Don’t compare yourself to friends you were better than.”

Comment: *You were better than your friends in the past, so don't compare yourself to them.*

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Robusto:

> Don't compare yourself to the friends you were better than.
>
> Don't compare yourself to the friends whom/that you were better than.

At least to me, it sounds good either of these ways. They have basically the same meaning as the original sentence and/or his.

Alternatively (and in my opinion this sounds more natural), you could just leave them apart:

> Don't compare yourself to your friends; you're better than them.

The use of the past tense seems like a weird clarification, but if you were to keep with it, just use one of the first two.

Something else to consider is what Lawrence has said: the comment by Robusto is ambiguous in that the first sentence could (and probably does) refer *only* to the friends you were better than and not to friends you weren't better than. Here, I'd think Jason Bassford is better and less ambiguous with just adding a conjunction between the two sentences.

I've made an additional sentence to address this ambiguity, although it doesn't sound as natural anymore:

> Don't compare yourself to your friends, whom you were better than.

Comment: Robusto's version isn't the same as the original. The original discourages comparison with *all* of the hearer's friends. In Robusto's version, only a subset of friends is to be excluded from comparison - namely, those the hearer is better than.

Comment: Consider: 1. "Don't eat the beans in the pot. They are red." 2. "Don't eat the red beans in the pot." #1 implies the pot only has red beans; none of the beans in the pot are to be eaten. #2 allows for (say) green beans in the pot to be eaten.

Comment: That is a good point.

Comment: @Lawrence: I was going for extreme economy, and to demonstrate how *whom* can safely be omitted. The OP has to decide which items to include and which to jettison. Beyond that, it's all counting how many angels can dance on the head of a pin.

Comment: @Robusto That makes sense (re *whom*). I was just noting to RW that the two sentences say different things.

Comment: @RobertW. The edit trail is available via the "edited (however long) ago" link at the bottom of your answer. Stack Exchange prefers our edited posts to look like a 'final draft' (rather than something like "... EDIT1 ... EDIT2 ... etc").

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful answers. I suppose it's better to leave the two sentences appart and all the versions you have suggested made sense . Robert said we can actually use whom after a coma , is the sentence in that case just odd or is it ungrammatical. Thank you .

Comment: @Zlam: You can use anything you like after a "coma" ... everyone will be pleased just to find you can talk again.

Comment: @Zlam: Robusto meant his last comment as a joke on the word "coma".